# ViewPager like of thing in BrowseFragment in AndroidTV

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tv

I am new in Android TV. Please have a look to the below attached image.

[image]

on the top of this picture there is a crousel and all the red marked area are the images.

i want to make this screen in Android TV. i have use BrowseFragment for this. I have use two Presenter one for First Row and another for other row.

The code which i have used :

**HomeFragment.java**

```
    private  CustomListRowPresenter mListRowPresenter;
    private void loadRows() {
        List<Movie> list = MovieList.setupMovies();
        mListRowPresenter = new CustomListRowPresenter(getActivity(),this);
        mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(mListRowPresenter);
        CardPresenter cardPresenter = new CardPresenter(getActivity());

        mNumberOfRows = NUM_ROWS;
        HeaderItem gridHeader = new HeaderItem(0, "");
        GridItemPresenter mGridPresenter = new GridItemPresenter();
        ArrayObjectAdapter gridRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(mGridPresenter);
        gridRowAdapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.grid_view));
        gridRowAdapter.add(getString(R.string.error_fragment));
        gridRowAdapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.personal_settings));
        mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(gridHeader, gridRowAdapter));

        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                Collections.shuffle(list);
            }
            ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter);
            for (int j = 1; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
                listRowAdapter.add(list.get(j % 5));
            }
            HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(i, MovieList.MOVIE_CATEGORY[i]);
            mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));
        }



        setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);

    }
```

**CardPresenter.java**

```
public class CardPresenter extends Presenter {
    private static final String TAG = "CardPresenter";

    private static int CARD_WIDTH = 360;
    private static int CARD_HEIGHT = 160;
    private static int sSelectedBackgroundColor;
    private static int sDefaultBackgroundColor;
    private Drawable mDefaultCardImage;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public CardPresenter(Activity activity){
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public CardPresenter(){
     }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder");

        sDefaultBackgroundColor = parent.getResources().getColor(R.color.default_background);
        sSelectedBackgroundColor = parent.getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_background);
        mDefaultCardImage = parent.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.movie);
/*
        ImageCardView cardView = new ImageCardView(parent.getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
                updateCardBackgroundColor(this, selected);
                super.setSelected(selected);
            }
        };

        cardView.setFocusable(true);
        cardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        cardView
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gridview_cell_border);
        updateCardBackgroundColor(cardView, false);*/

        View view = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gridview_cell_rows, parent,
                false);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.container_grid_view_item);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gridview_cell_border);

        view.setFocusable(true);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;

     }

    private static void updateCardBackgroundColor(ImageCardView view, boolean selected) {
        int color = selected ? sSelectedBackgroundColor : sDefaultBackgroundColor;
        // Both background colors should be set because the view's background is temporarily visible
        // during animations.
        view.setBackgroundColor(color);
        view.findViewById(R.id.info_field).setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {
        Movie movie = (Movie) item;
        View cardView = (View) viewHolder.view;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)cardView.findViewById(R.id.container_grid_view_item);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gridview_cell_border);
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder");
        if (movie.getCardImageUrl() != null) {
           /* cardView.setTitleText(movie.getTitle());
            cardView.setContentText(movie.getStudio());
            cardView.setMainImageDimensions(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);*/
            Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext())
                    .load(movie.getCardImageUrl())
                    .centerCrop()
                    .error(mDefaultCardImage)
                    .into(imageView);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onUnbindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onUnbindViewHolder");
        View cardView = (View) viewHolder.view;
        // Remove references to images so that the garbage collector can free up memory

    }
```

So for first row i have used CardPresenter and for other row i have used GridPresenter.

My Requirment is that this viewpager type of thing should be auto rotate in every 5 second.

So Please help me how can i design this fragment.

Comment: https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview will help you

Comment: Thanks @AnshulTyagi . can i use this library in android TV ?

Comment: Yes, I think it will.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi because in Android TV we are using BrowseFragment and the requirment is that the above crousel tray should be scroll to top during scroll.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi We can not use this library in Android TV. it is for mobile application.

Comment: @Can anyone give me any idea. i am stuck at this point.

Comment: I can't see your image so I'm having a hard time understanding what you'd like it to look like. Please try re-uploading the image.

Comment: @KyleVenn Please have a look. i have attached the image.

Comment: @nitintyagi do you got any solution for this

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi Yes i did that. I had customize BrowseFragment class and now we are using different-2 Presenter for displaying first row carousel and other rows

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [Creating a Catalog Browser](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/browse.html#header), if you wish to customize the header views between fragments, use a `Presenter` and implement the abstract methods to create, bind, and unbind the view holder. In the [**`BrowseFragment`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BrowseFragment.html) implementation that displays the catalog browser, use the `setHeaderPresenterSelector()` method to set the presenter for the row header or `setOnItemViewSelectedListener()` method to set an item selection listener, as shown in the following example.

```
setHeaderPresenterSelector(new PresenterSelector() {
    @Override
    public Presenter getPresenter(Object o) {
        return new IconHeaderItemPresenter();
    }
});
```

Then, set time duration of each page presenter using `Timer` as shown in this [GitHub post](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tvleanback/ui/MainFragment.java).

For sample code implementation, this [tutorial](http://corochann.com/android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-4-122.html) might also help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Now i am using the BrowseFragment and for the first row i am using the different Presenter. Now in this presenter i am using the ViewPager. Meanwhile i am not getting the same effect on scrolling as i get in BrowseFragment.     Please suggest is this the right approach or i need some diiferent to try.

Comment: can you give me an idea how to implement the above thing ?

Comment: @nitintyagi, Were u able to figure out a solution to implement Carousel on Android Tv. Any pointer would be of great help.

Comment: @user1273299 i was able to inlarge the first row image like the imgae attached in my question . but i was not able to give the functionality like auto scrolling for Carousel. if you need any help then ping me on skype nitin.ibt